# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, custom-cell

I'm using a custom cell:

```
class recordedSetUICell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var lblExerciseName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblSetNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var inp_txtReps: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var inp_txtWeight: UITextField! }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> recordedSetUICell {
    print(indexPath.row)
    var cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:indexPath) as! recordedSetUICell

    if let dequeuedcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? recordedSetUICell {
        cell = dequeuedcell
    } else {
        cell = recordedSetUICell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
```

I've declared the cell identifier in storyboard to 'cell' however i get the following error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: you need to register the cell first , look to my answer in duplicate ,  if you use a prototype cell then no register only set the identifier to it otherwise you have to register

Comment: Hi I've registered the cell, however it now crashes on execution saying 'Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' for the cell.lblExerciseName (or any other cell IBOutlet)